# vue3-easy-data-table / number of hits in search

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a vue3-easy-data-table with search options. Now I want to display the number of hits by search. Which variable or array can I use for this? I didn't find anything about this in the documentation. Thanks.

```
        <EasyDataTable :headers="headersAWSTable" :items="JSONArrayTransformedAWS" :rows-per-page="100"
          buttons-pagination alternating :search-field="searchField" :search-value="searchValue">
        </EasyDataTable>
```

Image with all hits of my array, after search i want to get the correct number of hits by search.

[image]

Comment: If the library doesn't expose this information, which it looks like it doesn't, you'd need to make a [feature request](https://github.com/HC200ok/vue3-easy-data-table/issues) on their github